# How to divide two by prometheus queries to calculate a percentage

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have two distinct metrics that both have a label of `client_app`.

One metric is a histogram that counts the number of failed requests for a given time span (i.e. 10 req in the last min failed) and the other metric is a counter that increments for every request.

I want to divide these two metrics to get a percentage of failed requests per client_app

Here is my attempt so far

```
avg by (client_app) (max(rate(ignored_events_sum[5m])) / sum(rate(total_app_events[5m])))
```

This only outputs a single graph whereas I am hoping for one per each client_app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
max by (client_app) (rate(ignored_events_sum[5m])) / sum by (client_app) (rate(total_app_events[5m]))
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Prometheus performs division over pairs of time series with identical sets of labels on the left and the right side of `/` according to [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches). If time series on the left and the right sides of `/` contain distinct sets of labels, then `on()` and `group_left()` modifiers may help:

- The `on()` modifier limits labels, which are used for searching for matching time series pairs. For example `a / on(client_app) b` would search for time series pairs from `a` and `b` with identical `client_app` label only.
- The `group_left()` modifier allows matching multiple time series with the given labelset on the left side of `/` with a single time series on the right side of `/`.

See more details about these modifiers [in these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches).

So the solution to the original question is the following PromQL query:

```
rate(ignored_events_count[5m])
  / on (client_app) group_left()
rate(total_app_events[5m])
```

It will divide per-seconds rates for each time series with `ignored_events_count` name by per-second rates for time series with `total_app_events` name with the matching `client_app` label value.