# Prometheus query to calculate percentage from two metrics with different set of labels

Tags: prometheus, grafana

We have a service that accepts the HTTP request and responds with all the matching user data in the response and produces two metrics that are supposed to be made available as graphs/charts on the grafana. Metrics as mentioned here -

1. Total requests received by the application in different data centre regions

   > application_requests_total{data_center_region_id=1} //200
   > application_requests_total{data_center_region_id=2} //100
2. Every request to the application will try and include all the matching user's data in the response metrics

   > application_response_total{user="user1, data_center_region_id=1} //100
   > application_response_total{user="user1, data_center_region_id=2} //100
   > application_response_total{user="user2, data_center_region_id=1} //50
   > application_response_total{user="user2, data_center_region_id=2} //100

**Quick observations on the metrics**

- `user` label is only present in response metrics `application_response_total`
- `data_center_region_id` is the common label in request and response metrics
- One response can contain more than one user's data which is also reflected in the metrics `application_response_total`.

I need to find out the percentage of the responses at the user level against the total requests made to the application in specific data centre region.

Eg: Based on the above data the expected results would be

**For data_center_region_id=1**

- user1's data responded for 100/200 = 50% of the time
- user2's data responded for 50/200 = 25% of the time

**For data_center_region_id=2**

- user1's data responded for 100/100 = 100% of the time
- user2's data responded for 100/100 = 100% of the time

I tried a couple of queries based on the [Prometheus vector matching documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) but couldn't achieve the expected results. Few samples queries as follows; I'm not sure but I think I messed up the `ON`/`IGNORING` and `GROUP_LEFT`/`GROUP_RIGHT` keyworkds

```
sum(rate(application_response_total{data_center_region_id=~"$region"}[5m])) by (user, data_center_region_id) / on(user) group_left(data_center_region_id) sum(rate(application_requests_total{data_center_region_id=~"$region"}[5m])) by (user, data_center_region_id)
```

Also took reference from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019337/how-to-divide-two-by-prometheus-queries-to-calculate-a-percentage) but nothing is working for me.

Please guide me with above-expected result;

Also, is this the only way to get the desired graphs?

Answer (score 0):

Note that it may be a bad idea to put `user` into metric labels if the application is going to serve unlimited number of users. This may result in e.g. [high cardinality issues](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-cardinality).

As for the original question, you need to put common labels for the left-side and right-side series in the `on(...)` modifier, so Prometheus could find pairs of series with the given labels on both sides of `/` operator. The following query returns per-(user, region) rps share:

```
rate(application_response_total[5m])
  / on(data_center_region_id) group_left()
rate(application_requests_total[5m])
```

The `group_left()` modifier instructs Prometheus that the left side may contain multiple series with the identical `data_center_region_id` label value. In this case Prometheus independently divides each such series by the series at the right side with the matching `data_center_rrgion_id` label value. The resulting series will have the same set of labels as the left-side series. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for details.